# Displaying a pop-up warning message on click checkbox in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an asp webpage. One of the elements in that asp page is an asp:repeater element as below:

```
<asp:repeater ID = repeater1 runat="Server" onitemdatabound="Repeater_ItemdataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
 <div class="row1">
 <span class="features">
 <asp:checkbox id="cb1" runat="server" />
 <asp:textbox id="tb1" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Text") %> />
 </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

When the user clicks on the "checkbox", a warning message should pop-up asking whether user really wants to select. The contents on the warning message, come from the data that is bound to the repeater. DataItem has a property "WarningText". The pop-up should appear only in certain cases when the warning message is not null.

I have very little experience with asp. I am not sure what should I be even looking for, if i had to find some online resources for this problem. I think I would have to use some client side scripting like javascript for this, but i do not know anything else. I would appreciate if someone can point me in right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the checkbox:

```
<asp:checkbox id="cb1" runat="server" onclick="return confirm('<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "WarningText") %>');" />
```

Comment: i do not see an onclick event for asp:checkbox. Is that something in the newer versions? I am on .Net 3.5

Comment: @Sandy it's just a basic html attribute. you might not get the intellisense for it but it will work.

Answer (score 0):

If the question you are asking is something like "How could I create a pop up message?" You could try looking into [JQuery Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

It would not be very hard to implement client or server side. If you need to determine if the pop up is showing server side you can use an `asp:Placeholder` with a nested dialog div inside it.

If you wanted to do it server side you can either do an `onclick` (if asp checkboxes have that) or add other functionality that will create a dialog.

If you already have text created and just need to know how to make it visible server side you can use `asp:Placeholder`s and do something like this:

HTML

```
<asp:Placeholder ID = "placeHolder"> ....
```

Code behind:

```
placeHolder.Visible = true/false;
```

(visible may be lowercase)

Hopefully that helps. Sorry if it doesn't, I was kind of having a hard time figuring out the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Protected Sub JavaAlert(ByVal strMsg As String)
    Dim alertScript As String = "<script language='javascript'>alert('" & strMsg & "')</script>"
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(Page), "PopupScript", alertScript)
End Sub
```